# Drop shadow effect

Tags: css, button

I'm trying to get a custom effect like a drop shadow. Only the color isn't one solid color but a pattern.

**See example image:**

[image]

I can achieve a solid color with a drop shadow, but is it possible to get this result?

Comment: Have you tried using `:after`?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] showing what you've tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can specify multiple effects separated by commas if you wish to do so.

[box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)

But I also recommend using `:after` and applying a `background-image: linear-gradient()` to it

Comment: Thanks! Should have thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/zjymfubo/1/

```
<div class="stripe"></div>

.stripe {
  height:20px;
  width:300px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}
.stripe:after {
  content: '';
  height:20px;
  width:300px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  z-index:-1;
  color: white;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    -45deg,
    #606dbc,
    #606dbc 5px,
    #465298 5px,
    #465298 10px
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS gradients to achieve this effect:

```
<div class="container"></div>

.container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 125px;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
}
.container::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
background: repeating-linear-gradient(
  -45deg,
  orange,
  orange 5px,
  white 5px,
  white 10px
);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Here's a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OzLExJ) example.

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/dakata911/pen/VyZdpV

```
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
}

.box:after {
  content: '';
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  background: red;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use :after

```css
    .shadow{
      height:50px;
      width:300px;
      position: relative;
      background-color: #fafafa;
    }
    .shadow:after {
      content: '';
      height:50px;
      width:300px;
      position: absolute;
      left: 6px;
      top: 6px;
      z-index:-1;
      color: #fff;
      background: repeating-linear-gradient(
        -45deg,
        #fff,
        #fff 5px,
        yellow 5px,
        yellow 10px
      );
    }
```

```html
<div class="shadow"></div>
```